# post request with express error can't set headers after sent to clients is it possible to use fetch inside post req

Tags: node.js, express

> i ran into a problem , when fetching an http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080 to another server from my localhost back-end server and i get this error, but when i disable the firewall on the other server , the post request is working for a period of times , then this error happens again can some one help me with this, i didn't write the post request , i just want to know why this error , happens sometimes , then it works another time , and i don't understand if it's firewall problem or tls , ssl certificates problem , or the problem is on my localhost , in the code that created the server ?

```
{ FetchError: request to http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/users failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT xx.xx.xx.xx:8080
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\deadpool\Desktop\server\node_modules\node-fetch\index.js:133:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:391:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  name: 'FetchError',
  message:
   'request to http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/users failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT xx.xx.xx.xx:8080',
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT' }
```

Comment: Are you sure after disabling the firewall of other server someone didnt enable it again?

Comment: And as per the example in app.post you are not sending any response. Did you use res.send, res.json or res.status or anything like that?

Comment: i updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i receive error can't set headers after sent to clients , the code is running but why this error happens

You are using res.json in a loop. You can call res.json only once in a route.

When you are calling res.json it sends all the response and headers and disconnects the http connection.

You have to edit your code so that res.json get called when all your business logic completed.

> and is there is a better way to write this code

Yes your code became very pathetic to read. Why don't you make multiple functions to do small small parts? By that you can reduce nested promises and make everything readable.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2691619/jayadratha-mondal
thanks for the info , that's what i'm working on now , i just wanted to be functional the review the code and add comments to be easy to read , thanks for your answer  :)